# Is there a Vista 64 bit alternative to Noteburner?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, audio, conversion, software-rec

I was an happy user of [Noteburner](http://www.noteburner.com/) on XP 32 bit but then I upgraded to Vista 64 bit.
I contacted their support and they confirmed it does not work but they don't have any date for a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your needs. I note that Noteburner also undoes DRM, and this requirement may narrow the field quite a bit. It might be that your best solution will be a combination of products, rather than one.

See Gizmo's article [Best Free Audio / Video Format Conversion Program](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-audio-video-format-conversion-program.htm) which discusses the merits of FormatFactory, Pazera Video Converters Suite, Quick Media Converter, MediaCoder and SUPER. One or more of them them should match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [Noteburner](http://www.noteburner.com) supports 64-bit systems.

Comment: I just tested on Vista 64 bit NoteBurner 2.31 and it worked fine. However I think that the original question and answer are still valid, you may want to find an alternative.